# How to sum the column which is have same Items

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I want to sum TU which is having same items...My table is
`TID ITEMS     TIMES  TU
1   D           5   136
1   M           5   136
1   R           14  136
4   D           2   106
4   B           6   106
4   H           1   106
5   D           1   97
5   B           6   97
5   M           6   97
7   D           4   77
7   B           2   77`
How to check the similar items in the table

Comment: eg..D is occurred in TID 1,4,5,7...i need to find similar items in the table and sum its TU

Comment: you want to do it in C# or in SQL Server?

Comment: both c# and sql server sir...

Comment: So, firstly you need to write query and then execute it from c#? Ok, which part of the query you have written?

Comment: yes sir...select TID,ITEMS,sum(TU) as TU Group by ITEMS...is it right???

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT items, SUM(tu)
FROM table
GROUP BY items
```